# How to convert Array of Objects (Multiple Classes) to Linked List of Objects? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, class, linked-list

I have 2 classes,

```
Class Students
{
   public:
   string name;
   int age;
   int stuID;
};
```

and

```
Class Marks
    {
       public;
       int stuID;
       float test1Mark;
       float test2Mark;
       float finalExamMark;
       
    };
```

Main(), below.

```
int main()
{
const size = 100;
Student stu[size];
Marks stuMarks[size];

populateObjects(stu, size);
}
```

Function to add data from a text file.

```
populateObjects(Student *stu, int size)
{
ifstream stuFile;
    stuFile.open("student.txt");
    
    stuFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
    
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        stuFile >> 
        stu[i].name >> 
        stu[i].age >>
        stu[i].stuID;
    }
    stuFile.close();
}
```

And a similar function to add data for the Marks Class (stuMarks[100] array).

Right now, I'm using an array of objects but I want to change it to use linked list of object. I am a beginner in c++ and just started learning about linked list. I know the basics of linked list but I am completely lost when it come to Linked Liast of Objects, Passing a linked list into a function and add data to a linked list from a .txt file. Any help will be much appreciated.

So, my main questions are:

1. How to convert array of objects (multiple objects) to linked list of objects?
2. How do I then pass the linked list to a function?
3. How do I add data to the linked list using a .txt file?

Comment: std::list linkedList(std::begin(stuMarks), std::end(stuMarks)); . Please only ask one question at a time.

Comment: I know students are taught to use linked lists, but in practice they are usually terrible. 99% of the time it is the wrong data structure to use. Keep your raw array, or use `std::array` or `std::vector`.